# Iframe scrolls to top on IPhone when submit button is clicked inside of it

Tags: ios, css, iframe

#### Introduction

At the end of our billing process the users will be directed to a page where they finish the process. This page, embeded in an iframe, is from someone else, so I have no access to its content.

#### The problem

All works correctly in all browsers and plattforms, except on an IPhone (tested Chrome and Safari there). When you click on the submit button it scrolls the iframe  to the top and nothing is submitted. interestingly when you press the button while scrolling and hold it for 2 seconds it works.

How can I get the submit button in the iframe to work?

**It is NOT the problem to scroll the iframe, the scrolling works on the IPhone.**

#### Example

Here is an example in **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVLoao)** and a snippet:

```css
iframe
{
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://labs-test.chargebee.com/pages/v2/e1Ny4GZ2oKxnF3cdy9jgbWBUAvp7EJ4RM/checkout" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

*Note: The Iframe used in the example is a example from a billing plattform, nothing will be bought if you test it with it (there is a fake valid card number sugested if you click in the field)*.

Comment: Your link is not working anymore (showing "Your order has already been submitted successfully") but can you check if the URL ends with '#' when clicking on Submit button ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue, but only on iOS.

Comment: @JoeEifert Sorry I havn't found a direct solution. I exchanged the inner page with a newer version and it worked